# Exported MDD doesn't match the original simulation

Tags: export, import, cloth-simulation

I had a task to make an animation of a fishing net that captures an object. When I try to bake cloth simulation to MDD and then apply it to new Plane mesh it for some reason doesn't preserve the exact same simulation.

[image]

I imported MDD with Mesh Cash modifier, however, it seems like there is a shift from original location, or as if cloth settings were different.
(Blue - original simulation, Green - imported MDD)

[image]

Details on model:

I used Hook to manipulate animation of clothes such it follows 4 Icospheres. Also I mirrored gravitation, so the animation happens in switched coordinates.
On Plane: Decimate and Wireframe modifiers, Cloth and Collision physics.
On CuBe: Collision and Soft Body(only Edges) physics.

I'm new to Blender, so maybe I'm just missing something. Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks!